# Creating rect Buttons with Pygame

Tags: python, button, pygame

I am trying to make buttons using `rect` in Pygame. I started with the red quit button and checked if a click was inside the boundingbox of the button.

```
    import pygame
"""import nemesis.py;"""

pygame.init();
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400,300));
pygame.display.set_caption("menu");
menuAtivo = True;

start_button = pygame.draw.rect(screen,(0,0,240),(150,90,100,50));
continue_button = pygame.draw.rect(screen,(0,244,0),(150,160,100,50));
quit_button = pygame.draw.rect(screen,(244,0,0),(150,230,100,50));


pygame.display.flip();


while menuAtivo:
    for evento in pygame.event.get():
        print(evento);
        if evento.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if pygame.mouse.get_pos() >= (150,230):
                if pygame.mouse.get_pos() <= (250,280):
                        pygame.quit();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TKS GUYS,

Here is my answer :

```
import pygame


pygame.init();
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400,300));
pygame.display.set_caption("menu");
menuAtivo = True;

start_button = pygame.draw.rect(screen,(0,0,240),(150,90,100,50));
continue_button = pygame.draw.rect(screen,(0,244,0),(150,160,100,50));
quit_button = pygame.draw.rect(screen,(244,0,0),(150,230,100,50));


pygame.display.flip();

def startGame():
    screen.fill((0,0,0));
    pygame.display.flip();
    import nemesis.py;

while menuAtivo:
    for evento in pygame.event.get():
        print(evento);
        if evento.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0] >= 150 and pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1] >= 230:
                if pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0] <= 250 and pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1] <= 280:
                        pygame.quit();
            if pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0] >= 150 and pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1] >= 90:
                if pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0] <= 250 and pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1] <= 140:
                        startGame();
```

Answer (score 8):

When using rects in pygame, it's best to use the in built collision detection.
here is an example code on how to do it hope it helps you solve your problem.

Before that though i'd like to mention you should render/draw your objects withing the while loop or the wont show up.

```
import pygame
import sys


def main():
    pygame.init()
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    fps = 60
    size = [200, 200]
    bg = [255, 255, 255]

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

    button = pygame.Rect(100, 100, 50, 50)  # creates a rect object
    # The rect method is similar to a list but with a few added perks
    # for example if you want the position of the button you can simpy type
    # button.x or button.y or if you want size you can type button.width or
    # height. you can also get the top, left, right and bottom of an object
    # with button.right, left, top, and bottom

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return False

            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                mouse_pos = event.pos  # gets mouse position

                # checks if mouse position is over the button

                if button.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
                    # prints current location of mouse
                    print('button was pressed at {0}'.format(mouse_pos))

        screen.fill(bg)

        pygame.draw.rect(screen, [255, 0, 0], button)  # draw button

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(fps)

    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 4):

Another good way to create buttons on pygame (in python) is by installing the package called pygame_widgets (pip3 install pygame_widgets) on Mac or Linux and (pip install pygame_widgets) on Windows. And also make sure you have pip installed otherwise, it is not going to work.

```
# Importing Modules
import pygame as pg
import pygame_widgets as pw
# creating screen
pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((800, 600))
running = True
button = pw.Button(
        screen, 100, 100, 300, 150, text='Hello',
        fontSize=50, margin=20,
        inactiveColour=(255, 0, 0),
        pressedColour=(0, 255, 0), radius=20,
        onClick=lambda: print('Click')
     )

while running:
      events = pg.event.get()
      for event in events:
           if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                running = False
      button.listen(events)
      button.draw()
      pg.display.update()
```

***Hope this helps you.***

Comment: Sadly it works on only python versions more than 3. Hope this helps. Bye

Answer (score 1):

I think the main problem in your code is that you compare pygame.mouse.get_pos() directly with a Tuple, which is ambiguous. You should try testing x then y separately:

```
while menuAtivo:
for evento in pygame.event.get():
    print(evento);
    if evento.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        if pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0] >= 150 and pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1] >= 230:
            if pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0] <= 250 and pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1] <= 280:
                    pygame.quit();
```

Answer (score 1):

I have already provided an answer on the above. Here is my another answer without the module pygame_widgets:

```
import pygame 
import sys 
  
  
# initializing the constructor 
pygame.init() 
  
# screen resolution 
res = (720,720) 
  
# opens up a window 
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(res) 
  
# white color 
color = (255,255,255) 
  
# light shade of the button 
color_light = (170,170,170) 
  
# dark shade of the button 
color_dark = (100,100,100) 
  
# stores the width of the 
# screen into a variable 
width = screen.get_width() 
  
# stores the height of the 
# screen into a variable 
height = screen.get_height() 
  
# defining a font 
smallfont = pygame.font.SysFont('Corbel',35) 
  
# rendering a text written in 
# this font 
text = smallfont.render('quit' , True , color) 
  
while True: 
      
    for ev in pygame.event.get(): 
          
        if ev.type == pygame.QUIT: 
            pygame.quit() 
              
        #checks if a mouse is clicked 
        if ev.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN: 
              
            #if the mouse is clicked on the 
            # button the game is terminated 
            if width/2 <= mouse[0] <= width/2+140 and height/2 <= mouse[1] <= height/2+40: 
                pygame.quit() 
                  
    # fills the screen with a color 
    screen.fill((60,25,60)) 
      
    # stores the (x,y) coordinates into 
    # the variable as a tuple 
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos() 
      
    # if mouse is hovered on a button it 
    # changes to lighter shade  
    if width/2 <= mouse[0] <= width/2+140 and height/2 <= mouse[1] <= height/2+40: 
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,color_light,[width/2,height/2,140,40]) 
          
    else: 
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,color_dark,[width/2,height/2,140,40]) 
      
    # superimposing the text onto our button 
    screen.blit(text , (width/2+50,height/2)) 
      
    # updates the frames of the game 
    pygame.display.update()
```

**Hope This Helps if pygame_widgets (pip install pygame_widgets) module could not be installed in your python version.**

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution

```
class button():
    def __init__(self, color, x,y,width,height, text=''):
        self.color = color
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.text = text

    def draw(self,win,outline=None):
        #Call this method to draw the button on the screen
        if outline:
            pygame.draw.rect(win, outline, (self.x-2,self.y-2,self.width+4,self.height+4),0)
            
        pygame.draw.rect(win, self.color, (self.x,self.y,self.width,self.height),0)
        
        if self.text != '':
            font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 60)
            text = font.render(self.text, 1, (0,0,0))
            win.blit(text, (self.x + (self.width/2 - text.get_width()/2), self.y + (self.height/2 - text.get_height()/2)))

    def isOver(self, pos):
        #Pos is the mouse position or a tuple of (x,y) coordinates
        if pos[0] > self.x and pos[0] < self.x + self.width:
            if pos[1] > self.y and pos[1] < self.y + self.height:
                return True
            
        return False
```

Comment: Code dumps do not make for good answers. You should explain *how* and *why* this solves their problem. I recommend reading, "[How do I write a good answer?"](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)